# How can I group TableView items from a dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Lets consider this example:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var names = ["Vegetables": ["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"], "Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"]]

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")

    return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return ???
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{      
    return names.count
    }

    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]!{

    return ???
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{        
    return ????
    }
}
```

let's assume that we need that the keys (fruits and vegetables) of the dictionary are the number of sections, plus they will be the titles of the sections. The items of the keys (eg apples and banana) will be the rows of each section. How can I implement this in my code? I know it might be easy but I couldn't figure it out my self.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use struct for that and here is example:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var names = ["Vegetables": ["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"], "Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"]]

    struct Objects {

        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObjects : [String]!
    }

    var objectArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (key, value) in names {
            println("\(key) -> \(value)")
            objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return objectArray[section].sectionName
    }
}
```

Comment: I did! Your answer provided more than I expected! :)

Comment: Good luck with your project..:)

Comment: one more question if possible, can you tell me how can I sort sections alphabetically?

Comment: How do I implement search on this tableView?

Comment: Yes, this is great.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I created a class like is tis  ```<public class SomeResponse : Codable {
    var dic : [String:[String]]?
    
    public init(dic:[String:[String]]?) {
        
        self.dic = dic
    }
}``` and API is giving the response exactly like *["Vegetables": ["Tomato", "Potato"], "Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"]]* then I have to show API response into TableView from ```SomeResponse``` class. Could help me out with this how-to assign API response to ```SomeResponse```?

Answer (score 28):

**Swift 2**

you dictionary example

```
var dic:Dictionary<String,String> = ["key":"value","key1":"value2"]
```

**Your table**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var key   = Array(self.dic.keys)[indexPath.row]
    var value = Array(self.dic.values)[indexPath.row]
    cell.text = key + value 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want it sorted use the global sorted function to sort the dictionary.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var names = ["Vegetables": ["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"], "Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"]]

    var namesSorted = [String, Array<String>]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Sort names
        namesSorted = sorted(names) { $0.0 < $1.0} // namesSorted = ["Fruits": ["Apple", "Banana"], "Vegetables": ["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"]]

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return namesSorted.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesSorted[section].1.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesSorted[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return namesSorted[section].0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All collection types must be Array

```
var names = [["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"], ["Apple", "Banana"]]
var sectionNames = ["Vegetables", "Fruits"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  return names[section].count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
  return names.count
}

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]!{

  return sectionNames
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    return sectionNames[section]
}
```

Comment: @Lamar I don't understand. Group how? And what do you mean with *same name*? There are two sections with different names.

Comment: what if I had multiple sections of the same name but they all had different data; for example `var names = [["Tomato", "Potato", "Lettuce"], ["Apple", "Banana"],["orange","pinapple"]]
var sectionNames = ["Vegetables", "Fruits","Fruits"]`   how would you group all the fruits into one section without the UI displaying two different sections

Comment: @Lamar Eventually the table view data source expects one array per section, so you have two options: Consolidate the affected arrays or write code to pretend to be one array. The most efficient way is the first one.

Answer (score 2):

> From Apple Documentation :
>
> `var keys: LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<Key, Value>, Key>> { get }`
>
> `Description`: A collection containing just the keys of self. Keys appear in the same order as they occur as the .0 member of key-value pairs in self. Each key in the result has a unique value.

`names.keys.array` returns an `Array` of the keys.

SO:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
return names.keys.array[section].count
}

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]!{
return names.keys.array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{        
return names.keys.array[section]
}
```

This will work on Any Dictionary with any amount of data(even if it is unknown to the programmer

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.  It is a bad idea to depend on `names.keys.array` always returning in the same order.  It would be better to do this once (and perhaps sort it) and keep the array in a property.

Comment: Yeah but In an UITableView where you are just displaying Data. Sorting doesn't matter.

Comment: Swift doesn't guarantee that `names.keys.array` will return the array in the same order on two consecutive calls.  You could get `[Fruits, Vegetables]` the first time you call it and `[Vegetables, Fruits]` the second time you call it and this would be perfectly legal.  You could end up showing a table with `Fruits` as the title of your first section and `Fruits` as the title of your second section if they aren't based upon the same single call to `names.keys.array`.

Comment: From Apple Documentation : `var keys: LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<Key, Value>, Key>> { get }`
`Description`: 
A collection containing just the keys of self.  
Keys appear in the same order as they occur as the .0 member of key-value pairs in self. Each key in the result has a unique value.

Comment: Interesting.  Then it's probably OK for a static dictionary, but for one in which keys are being inserted and deleted you'd be better off managing the order of your keys in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to solve this problem is to copy your dictionary into a temporary variable. Use `removeFirst` to extract the values from the array inside the dictionary.

```
var itemList=["Grocery":["soap","flour","carrots"],"Vehicles":["oil change","gas","tire rotation"],"Household":["Cable","Tv","cellphone"]]
var itemListTmp :[String:[String]] = [:]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=itemListTmp[keysItem[indexPath.section]]?.removeFirst()
       //cell.textLabel?.text=itemList[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Another way of solving this problem is to extract keys and values in separate arrays:

```
var task=[String](itemList.keys)
var tobeDone=[[String]](itemList.values)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return task[section]
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text=tobeDone[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136537/11098567 answer I would use classes instead of structs, so that you can manipulate or add to your values after it has been placed into the array.

@objc func addToInitialClassInstance() {

> ```
>    let classInstance = Class(property1: String, property2: [CLass2.init(property1: String, property2: String)])
>     let isAvailable = initialClassInstance.contains { (classInArray) -> Bool in
>         if classInArray.property == classInstance.property {
>             classInArray.property2.append(classInstance.property2[0])
>             return true
>         }
>         return false
>     }
>     if !isAvailable {
>         initialClassInstance.append(classInstance)
>     }
>     tableView.reloadData()
> }
> ```