# How to show separate View(box) in between tableview in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

In this screen how to show (blue view) in between tableview rows

[design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWT6d.png)

**code:** in storyboard design i have given all static data in labels and images so with this below code i am getting all cells like above screen shot, but after three cells how to show blue box view, please suggest me

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return 5
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BidCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use a different UITableViewCell class (probably what you are looking for?)
2. Use sections

### How?

You can either create a new UITableViewCell prototype cell in your storyboard or do it programmatically.
Create a custom UITableViewCell as such:

```swift
class OfferTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

}

// If you are not using storyboards, add the following code
// in your viewDidLoad
tableView.register(OfferTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "your_cell_id")
```

Then, you can dequeue the newly created cell at any index as such:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 10 // Index of the different cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your_cell_id", for: indexPath) as! OfferTableViewCell
        // Do cell configuration here
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BidCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this cell is going to take the place of another cell if you are using an array as datasource, so using `myArray.count` for your `numberOfRowsInSection` would result in *the last array element missing*. You will have to take that into account.

**Resources**

- [Using multiple custom cells in a TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776750/17026411)
- [UITableView sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31138332/17026411)
- [Custom header for TableView sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177906/17026411)

Comment: i am doing ur 1st option.. but when i use two prototype cells i am getting second cell height also the first cell height.. how to change second cell height.. `NOTE: i am not using sections to change height`

Comment: @User123 inside the `heightForRowAt` perform the same check on the value of `indexPath.row`. I suggest you do the same for `estimatedHeightForRowAt`